# VS 2017 for Mac Azure Function Unable to configure java worker. Could not find JAVA_HOME app setting

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-mac, azure-functions-core-tools

I am in the process of creating an Azure Function Apps project. I get
the following error when running the server.

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path:
/Users/dentonsavage/Projects/AzureFunctionTest/AzureFunctionTest/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0

Now listening on: http://localhost:7071 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
[7/9/18 9:48:39 PM] Reading host configuration file '/Users/dentonsavage/Projects/AzureFunctionTest/AzureFunctionTest/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/host.json'
[7/9/18 9:48:39 PM] Host configuration file read:{} 
[7/9/18 9:48:39 PM] Starting Host (HostId=shoufu-1532713004, InstanceId=9869d715-4618-48f0-b0d1-16c4fea66dba, Version=2.0.11651.0, ProcessId=43170, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, FunctionsExtensionVersion=) 
[7/9/18 9:48:40 PM] Unable to configure java worker. Could not find JAVA_HOME app setting.
[7/9/18 9:48:40 PM] Could not configure language worker Java. 
[7/9/18 9:48:41 PM] Generating 1 job function(s) 
[7/9/18 9:48:41 PM] Found the following functions: 
[7/9/18 9:48:41 PM] AzureFunctionTest.HttpTrigger.Run
[7/9/18 9:48:41 PM] Host initialized (2120ms) Listening on
http://localhost:7071/ Hit CTRL-C to exit...

Http Functions:

HttpTrigger: http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger

[7/9/18 9:48:43 PM] Host started (3920ms) 
[7/9/18 9:48:43 PM] Job host started 
[7/9/18 9:48:44 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000C475F100'.
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not an error. It's just a tip reminding us there's no `JAVA_HOME` configuration in your system environment variables.

It was used for java development before but has been proved unnecessary and removed in new version Azure Function core tools. See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2920).

So you can just ignore this harmless tip or install latest version function core tools to get rid of it.

Installation Steps:

- Install [.NET Core for macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/macos).
- Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), if it's not already installed.
- Install the Core Tools package using bash:

  ```
  brew tap azure/functions
  brew install azure-functions-core-tools
  ```

After that navigate to Content root path:

```
/Users/dentonsavage/Projects/AzureFunctionTest/AzureFunctionTest/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0
```

Then input `func start` in bash to debug your project.

Comment: @DentonSavage Just check my old answers at the start of new year, Could you accept the answer if it does help?